# XML Sitemap may have max 50.000 URLs. Say I have 1 <url> with 2 <image:image>'s. How many are left? 49.999 or 49.997?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

I have a very simple question. An XML Sitemap may have max 50.000 URLs. Say I have 1 < url> with 2 < image:image>'s. How many are left? 49.999 or 49.997?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can we tell without seeing the XML?  It could be both.  Depends on if the 50,000 in referring to parent nodes, which most likely it is, which would mean you have 49,999 left.  But with that said, who knows.

Edit...I just realized maybe you are talking about a google sitemap.  You can have 50,000 parent nodes, the inner nodes are not counted.

Comment: I mean a Google sitemap indeed, so if only the parent nodes count, the answer would be 49.999. Thanks!

Comment: Please mark as the answer to close the question out.